# Size of finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ such that the sum of reciprocals is a given positive integer

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers. For every integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let $m(k)$ denote the minimal size of a finite set $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{j\in S}j^{-1}=k$.

What is the asymptotic growth of $m(k)$?

Comment: You re asking in the wrong forum.

Comment: I think this is somewhat related to harmonic numbers and the euler constant

Comment: Apologies to @GeraldEdgar, I changed the question (it also contained a typo).

Comment: The sum of $N$ different Egyptian fractions (fractions with numerator 1 and positive integer denominator) is at most $\log N+O(1)$, that implies the exponential lower bound for $m(k)$.

Comment: Thanks @FedorPetrov, can you post this as an answer so we can close this thread?

Comment: The keyword for this is "Egyptian fractions".  A related question is at math.se ... https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185675/442 ... no "answer" is given there, either.

Comment: ... but a comment there does mention the exponential lower bound.

Comment: Ernie Croot has some papers about Egyptian fractions that you might find worth a look.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I suggest to change the question to "what is the asymptotic growth of $m(k)$" (even if the exponential lower bound is enough for you purpose, I think it is quite interesting in general to hold here).

Comment: Thanks @FedorPetrov I will change the question!

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of my question exact packing of the harmonic series. I conjecture (and probably am not the first to do so) that the answer is O(exp(k+1)). Further, I suspect a minimal set has all its members with denominators less than exp(k+1).  Gerhard "Whose Line Is It Anyway?" Paseman, 2019.05.27.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Ernie Croot](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematika/article/on-some-questions-of-erdos-and-graham-about-egyptian-fractions/2A5528F5D4173BCEC7E6FB4469D18812) showed that for all large $N$, every positive integer below 
$$
\sum_{n\le N} \frac 1n - \Big(\frac{9}{2}+o(1)\Big) \frac{(\log \log N)^2}{\log N}
$$ 
can be represented as a sum of unit fractions with denominator below $N$.  Clearly 
no integer larger than $\sum_{n\le N} 1/n$ can be so represented.  This gives the desired asymptotic growth for $m(k)$:  namely 
$$ 
m(k) = \exp(k-\gamma+ o(1)). 
$$